# stress test a website with webscrapig

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, stress-testing

My friend wrote a website by node.js, and I want to help him to do the stress test just in case it crashed some day. I used beautifulsoup to test it, and it went well.

Code:

```
for i in range(0,1000):
    #i=i+1
    l=randint(2008, 2018)
    first="year=%d" %l
    k=randint(1600, 2400)
    second="cc=%d" %k
    url="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/outputData?{0}&{1}&submit=Submit".format(first,second)
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    print(soup)
```

Instead of running 1000 times one by one in order, is there any other way to test it if I want to run it at the same time with 1000 codes by using python? Thanks!

Comment: If you are parsing the page unnecessarily with BeautifulSoup you are going to stress test your computer instead of the server when running in parallel.

Comment: In your code above, why would you do `i = i+1` in second lines within a for-loop?

Comment: @R.yan I thought I might need to use it after, but yeah that line is not necessary

Comment: @KlausD. Could you please provide more information? I've never done this before, so I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Parsing the result is (a) very expensive compared to retrieving it and (b) not related to testing the performance of the server since it happens on the client. You will put more load on the test client than on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `threading`. But I don't recommend to create 1000 thread and run it at the same time.

```
import threading
def testit():
    l=randint(2008, 2018)
    first="year=%d" %l
    k=randint(1600, 2400)
    second="cc=%d" %k
    url="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/outputData?{0}&{1}&submit=Submit".format(first,second)
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    print(soup) 

threads = [threading.Thread(target=testit) for i in range(1000)] # Not recommend to use 1000 here

for t in thread:
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use threads. Open up `n` threads, and ping the server at the same time. You can look into https://www.python-course.eu/threads.php

But running threads is a CPU intensive task, so make sure you keep `n` controlled. Giving a higher value to `n`, could stress the client.

Comment: Also, from experience, if you want to get rid of the `n`  and take it to next level. Look into multiprocessing setups(multiple machines e.g. aws lambda). It's more like pinging the server from `n` different computers. So neither of the computers are stressed, and enough load is put on the servers. Here you can spawn enough instances, and within  each instance you can run multiple threads. Taking it to next level!! 
When I did it, I exceeded total number of database connections, causing a downtime.